# Netbean doesn't accept a folder as a project

Tags: deployment, ejb

I am reading the book EJB 3 2nd by Apress. Together with the book is sample code. In chapter 2, there is a tutorial to deploy the project. According to the book I should do the following:

- in Netbean, choose Open Projects
- navigate to the folder of the sample code (that is the folder "Chapter02-SessionSamples")
- in the Open Project Window, in Project Name field , there should be Chapter02-SessionSamples
- under this field, check on Open Required Projects, with the 2 files ejb and war
- click finish and use Netbean to deploy the project

in the book, it's like this :

[image]

in my computer, it's like this :

[image]

My problem (as you can see in the picture) is that Netbean treats my sample code folder like a normal folder, and it can't identify it's a project. 
I wonder what is missed in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click File -> New Project
2. Then choose General -> Java Project with Existing Sources.Click next
3. In the Project name field,type a name in the blank
4. Click Browse besides Project Folder,set project path,then click next
5. In  Source Packages Folder pane,click Add Folder, navigate to Chapter02-SessionSamples,then select src folder
6. Click finish

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try "Java Project with Existing Sources" but it doesn't the created project does not have ejb and war directory as the picture in the book. However, I give that up, I switch to the EJB tutorial trail on the website by Netbean. Anyway, thank you again!